# Make on submit event wait for user input? JS

Tags: javascript

To make it clearer.
JavaScript.
I need to replicate the behaviour of a confirm() but without using a confirm() xd.

So basically, i have to stop the submit and wait for a true/false value from the user and the submit the form.

Now i´m preventing the form submit and then when the user click "yes" force the submit again with a .submit().

But i don´t know if is there any way to keep the on submit event waiting for a true or false return from another function.

Thank you.

Edit: I´ve just realized i can´t do a .submit() cause it will launch the onsubmit even again.

Comment: Maybe look at jquery to prevent submit and do your thing.

Comment: show some effot so people can help you. Display a div or something like that, then attach listeners to identify a clicked option and then run a call back.

Comment: Use button event to show confirm, trigger submit when confirmed

Answer (score 0):

With confirm():

```js
document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = function() {
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')) {
    // Do something
  }
    // Don't do something
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" name="input" />
  <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
```

Without confirm():

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('submit-button');
var confirm = document.getElementById('confirm-button');
var cancel = document.getElementById('cancel-button');

document.getElementById('submit-button').onclick = function() {
  submit.style.display = 'none';
  confirm.style.display = 'inline';
  cancel.style.display = 'inline';
}

document.getElementById('confirm-button').onclick = function() {
  // Submit form
}

document.getElementById('cancel-button').onclick = function() {
  submit.style.display = 'inline';
  confirm.style.display = 'none';
  cancel.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" name="input" />
  <button id="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button id="confirm-button" type="submit" style="display: none;">Confirm</button>
  <button id="cancel-button" type="submit" style="display: none;">Cancel</button>
</body>
```